# Extract user id numbers from a .csv file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a csv file with user information. A sample from the file is as below.

```
 "userType": "NORMAL",   "accountID": "J123456789"
 "userType": "NORMAL",   "accountID": "J987654321"
 "userType": "NORMAL",   "accountID": "C123456789"
 "userType": "NORMAL",   "accountID": "R987654321"
```

I want to obtain the id numbers using regex with python 3.

The regex I used was `("accountID": ")\w+` and it generates the following result.

```
"accountID": "J123456789
"accountID": "J987654321
"accountID": "C123456789
"accountID": "R987654321
```

The desired output should be like following,

```
J987654321
J987654321
C123456789
R987654321
```

Comment: Use `"accountID": "(\w+)` with `re.findall`

Comment: And for the sake of interest please: why does this task need `re`?

Comment: If you have `"accountID": "J123456789"`, how come you expect `J987654321`?

Answer (score 0):

If the file format is fixed consider detecting dialect automatically:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
    csvfile.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
    accounts = [row[2] for row in reader]
```

This code will produce the following list:

```
accounts
['J000025574', 'J000025620', 'C000025623', 'R000025624']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following regex `"(?:\"accountID\": \")(\S+)\"` that cature only Ids and ignore remaining part

```
import re

s = """"userType": "NORMAL",   "accountID": "J123456789"
 "userType": "NORMAL",   "accountID": "J987654321"
 "userType": "NORMAL",   "accountID": "C123456789"
 "userType": "NORMAL",   "accountID": "R987654321" """

print(re.findall("(?:\"accountID\": \")(\S+)\"",s))
```

result:

```
['J123456789', 'J987654321', 'C123456789', 'R987654321']
```

Answer (score 0):

Imho, this does not need any imports at all:

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip()[-11:-1])
```

or if the lengths of the account ids really vary, use:

```
        print(line.split('"')[-2])
```

within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could write yourself a parser (might be a bit over the top though):

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor

text = """
 "userType": "NORMAL",   "accountID": "J123456789"
 "userType": "NORMAL",   "accountID": "J987654321"
 "userType": "NORMAL",   "accountID": "C123456789"
 "userType": "NORMAL",   "accountID": "R987654321"
"""

grammar = Grammar(
    r"""
    file        = entry+

    entry       = garbage? (pair)+ newline
    pair        = ws? key equal value comma?

    key         = quotes word quotes
    value       = quotes word quotes
    quotes      = '"'
    word        = ~"\w+"
    equal       = ws? ":" ws?
    comma       = ws? "," ws?

    ws          = ~"[\t ]+"
    newline     = ~"[\r\n]"
    garbage     = (ws / newline)+
    """
)

tree = grammar.parse(text)

class Vistor(NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, needle):
        self.needle = needle

    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return visited_children or node

    def visit_key(self, node, children):
        _, key, _ = children
        return key

    def visit_value(self, node, children):
        _, value, _ = children
        return value

    def visit_pair(self, node, children):
        _, key, _, value, _ = children
        return (key, value)

    def visit_entry(self, node, children):
        _, entry, _ = children
        return entry

    def visit_file(self, node, children):
        out = [value.text
               for child in children if isinstance(child, list)
               for key, value in child
               if key.text == self.needle]
        return out

v = Vistor("accountID")
out = v.visit(tree)
print(out)
```

Which yields

```
['J123456789', 'J987654321', 'C123456789', 'R987654321']
```

Comment: ...and if it is not recommended - why proposing it as an answer then?

Comment: @SpghttCd: I am a bit ambivalent. On the one side, this is the more accurate way for structured information, on the other side this may seem a bit over the top for a one time task.